# On the irrelevance of the global phase factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, quantum-states

**Theory:**

Let's look at qubits. A qubit is a abstract quantum system that stands for 1 property of a real physical quantum system (e.g. the position of a particle in 2 wells). A state of a qubit is formally described by a complex vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with length 1 (using the standard scalar product).

I know that "the global phase can be ignored" (as Nielsen and Chuang put it) or "doesn't change the probabilities of getting a measurement result" (as one can check by oneself).

**Question(s):**

1. Now, this might lead to one thinking one could set "$|\psi_1\rangle ≡|\psi_2\rangle$ if $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ Is that the case?

2. One could follow from the theory that "$|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are formal descriptions for the same state of the qubit $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ . Is that the case?

I read (on Wikipedia) that $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ (with $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$) cannot be interchanged and describe the same (physical) state.

This makes me doubt 1.

What makes me doubt 2. is that there might be a difference between "a physical state" and "a state of a qubit" (the way I defined it above). But, if qubits stand for a certain real physical property, this cannot be.

---

To put it another way: Nakahara (978-1-4200-1229-3) says $|\psi_1\rangle$ actually represents a "ray" $\{e^{i\theta} |\psi_1\rangle|\theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$ because the global phase can be chosen arbitrarily. Still, there is a difference between $|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle\otimes e^{i\theta}|\psi_1\rangle$.

The first argument clearly allows to interchange $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$, the second doesn't. So there is some contradiction here.

I tried my best to put my confusion into words. I would appreciate anyone trying to clear things up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us clarify some of the words and concepts you use in your post.

First, a *system* is represented by a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. A *state* of that system is represented by a ray associated with a normalized vector $\lvert \psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}$. The ray associated with this normalized vector $\lvert \psi \rangle$ is correctly given by your post as the set $\{e^{i\phi} \lvert \psi \rangle: \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Formally, a ray is an equivalence class of vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ defined by the equivalence relation $\lvert \psi \rangle \sim \lvert \varphi \rangle $ iff $\lvert \psi \rangle = e^{i\theta} \lvert \varphi \rangle$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Discarding or including a global phase has no measurable effect. Hence, $\lvert \psi \rangle$ and $e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle$ do infact represent the exact same state of your system. This is the motivation in the first place for defining states as rays and not vectors.

If we have two systems $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ and we want to consider the composite system, we end up with a tensor product space $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. A state of this tensor product system might look like $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle_2$ where $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle_2 \in \mathcal{H}_2$.

The state *is* $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle_2 = e^{i\theta} (\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2) \sim \lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2$. So, this is the same situation as the simpler, non-tensor product space state. Namely, we have two equivalent representations of the same state, so you can choose WLOG to use either of them.

However, it would not make sense to say that $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2 = \lvert \psi \rangle_2 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_1$ or even $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2 \sim \lvert \psi \rangle_2 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_1$ because that would be saying that $\lvert \psi \rangle_2 \in \mathcal{H}_1$ which is certainly not true as $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are two entirely different spaces!

Comment: I can follow your explanation and do understand it. So following "The state *is* $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle_2 = e^{i\theta} (\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2) \sim \lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2$" - one is allowed to interchange, no?

Comment: I made a recent edit, which touches on why you cannot interchange $\lvert \psi \rangle_1$ and $\lvert \psi \rangle_2$. I think it might have not loaded since I made it quite recently. Let me know if this edit helps or not! @manuel459

Comment: Let me clarify: By interchanging I mean replacing $|\psi_2\rangle$ in e.g. $|\psi_1\rangle\otimes|\psi_2\rangle$ with $e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ if all this happens in some calculation.

Comment: Ah! That is my bad. Yes you can interchange them, then. As hft mentions they are not mathematically equal (e.g. as 1 = 1), but they are mathematically equivalent with respect to what we (as people studying quantum mechanics) care about, so we can use whatever ray we'd like without affecting the physics whatsoever. @manuel459

Comment: Okay. Follow me here for a sec. If one is allowed to do it, why does wikipedia say the following: "even though $|\psi\rangle$ and $e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ correspond to the same physical quantum state, they are not interchangable, since $|\phi\rangle+|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle+e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ will not correspond to the same physical state"? Is it interchangable (in my above sense) or not? I mean if one replaces it mid some calculation and way later comes to that superposition, you would have to know in advance that this comes up and not interchange in the first place.

Comment: I will respond with more details in a little bit, but there is an answer to your question :-) @manuel459. In short, what Wikipedia says is correct. What I said in the context of the particular example we were talking about is also correct.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I can tell that both is correct. But somehow it still doesn't add up for me :/.

Comment: If our state is $\lvert \varphi \rangle = \lvert \phi \rangle + e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle$, then $\lvert \varphi \rangle \sim e^{i\alpha} \lvert \varphi \rangle$. I.e., we can vary by a global phase. If instead we vary by a "local" phase as you suggest to do, we get $\lvert \phi \rangle + e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle \not\sim \lvert \phi \rangle + \lvert \psi \rangle$ because the LHS and RHS are not related by a global phase. @manuel459

Comment: In the particular case I provided in my answer, $\lvert \varphi \rangle = \lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes e^{i\theta} \lvert \psi \rangle_2 = e^{i\theta} (\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2)$. We can pull out the entire phase due to how tensor products work. This is a very different situation from adding two states together as you can probably see.

Comment: I think the general way to think of it is: Determine what your state is. Not the states making up your state, the actual, full state. E.g., $\lvert \varphi \rangle = \lvert \psi \rangle + \lvert \phi \rangle$ is the full state, not $\lvert \phi \rangle$. It is this full state that you can add or take away an arbitrary phase from. Not to any of its constituents. In the case where your state is simple like $\lvert \varphi \rangle = \lvert \phi \rangle$, it looks like you are swapping individual states, but this is just a particularly simple application of the aforementioned general rule.

Comment: I think I got it now. One more thing: What is the difference between writing $|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle$ (if they only differ by a global phase) and $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$? Rational numbers are also defined by equivalence classes and there (somehow) one may write "="?

Comment: Also, do you know any book that says that states are formally described by an equivalent relation $\{e^{i\gamma}|\psi\rangle\}$? So far I only found something similar in Marinescus "Classical and Quantum Information" but the definition there is as "an equivalence class of vectors that differ by multiplication by a nonzero complex scalar" where one usually chooses "an element of this class (for any nonvanishing vector) to have unit norm"

Comment: In the case of rational numbers, I think we are using each element of a given equivalence class as a representative of the entire equivalence class. So, when we write down the symbol $1/2$ what we are really writing down is the equivalence class containing $1/2$. Hence $1/2 = 2/4$, since they are the same equivalence class. But in this quantum case, perhaps we are referring literally to a vector in the Hilbert space when we write a ket.

Comment: See Steven Weinberg’s The Quantum Theory of Fields vol. 1. The beginning of chapter 2 briefly but accurately describes states as rays (and then proceeds to talk about transformations of states). @manuel459

Comment: please see the chat for one further comment of mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that "the global phase can be ignored" (as Nielsen and Chuang put it) or "doesn't change the probabilities of getting a measurement result" (as one can check by oneself).

Here's another quote from Nielsen and Chuang: "We say that the state $e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ is equal to $|\psi\rangle$, **up to the *global phase factor*** $e^{i\theta}$" (Bold emphasis added, italics in original.)

We do not say they literally "are equal." Because they are not literally equal.

For example, consider the computational basis state $|0\rangle$ in the simplest matrix representation:
$$
|0\rangle \to\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)\;.
$$
The above is not *literally* equal to:
$$
e^{i\theta}|0\rangle \to\left(\begin{matrix} e^{i\theta} \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
unless $\theta = 2\pi n$ for n = 0, 1, 2, etc.

We say that these two different vectors "are equal **up to a global phase factor**," which is a fancy way of saying they are not strictly equal, but we don't usually care.

Nielsen and Chuang aren't being super careful about whether they mean the state of the physical system or the vector representing that state in Hilbert space.

What one should say, following Messiah (e.g., at page 296), is that $|\psi\rangle$ is vector (or ket) in Hilbert space and it represents the dynamical state of the physical system, but it is not a unique representation of the dynamical state of the physical system, since $e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ also represents the dynamical state of the physical system.

> 1. Now, this might lead to one thinking one could set "$|\psi_1\rangle ≡|\psi_2\rangle$ if $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ Is that the case?

No. You can not literally set them equal because they are not literally equal.

If you want to make such a replacement in an expectation value, that is fine. The expectation value will remain the same.

> 2. One could follow from the theory that "$|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are formal descriptions for the same state of the qubit $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ . Is that the case?

They can both be used to describe the same physical state. But they are not literally equal.

> I read (on wikipedia) that $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ (with $|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\theta}|\psi_2\rangle$ for a $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$) cannot be interchanged and describe the same (physical) state.

That's fine.

> What makes me doubt 2. is that there might be a difference between "a physical state" and "a state of a qubit" (the way I defined it above). But, if qubits stand for a certain real physical property, this cannot be.

OK. That's fine too.

---

**Update:**

> Still, there is a difference between $|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle\otimes e^{i\theta}|\psi_1\rangle$.

Yes, there is a literal difference. Suppose that both your $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are the computation basis state $|0\rangle$.

Then you have:
$$
|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\psi_1\rangle \to \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
and
$$
|\psi_2\rangle\otimes e^{i\theta}|\psi_1\rangle \to \left(\begin{matrix} e^{i\theta} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
which is literally different if theta is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So "up to a global phase factor" or the ray argument I brought up means that one could definie equivalence classes right? Why don't equivalence classes allow for a interchange if one calculates using these? Could you maybe put your answer into perspective relative to states of qubits (qubits defined as an abstract quantum system that stands for one single property of a real physical system)? What I am going afteris the following: I am not allowed to identify "the state of a qubit" with the formal representation of it (even if that is somewhat new to me). Right?

Comment: "I am not allowed to identify "the state of a qubit" with the formal representation of it (even if that is somewhat new to me). Right?" Yes, that sounds pretty much right.

Comment: Another way to think of it is: If $\psi(x,t)$ is a solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation, then so is $e^{i\theta}\psi(x,t)$.

Comment: I guess that was my problem. Because all the time (in textbooks etc.) one would say "the state $|\psi\rangle$" and state $|\psi\rangle=(1,0)^T$ somewhere else. Which led me to believe I was allowed to identify "the state of a qubit" and its formal representation. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, the language can be pretty loose sometimes